# Use Storyboard code to work from Resource Dictionary in Windows Universal App

Tags: storyboard, winrt-xaml, windows-8.1, windows-phone-8.1, win-universal-app

Need a little help regarding Storyboard in here. In my MainPage.xaml, I have a Code of Storyboard like the following:

```
<Page.Resources>
    <Storyboard x:Name="BackStoryBoard">
        <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="4.55" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(CompositeTransform.ScaleX)" Storyboard.TargetName="image" d:IsOptimized="True"/>
        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames AutoReverse="True" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(CompositeTransform.TranslateX)" Storyboard.TargetName="image">
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="710"/>
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:30" Value="-710"/>
        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
    </Storyboard>
</Page.Resources>
```

Now, in my Grid, I have a Code of Image like the following (I have only one Grid):

```
<Grid>
    <Image x:Name="image" Source="Images/Background4.png" Stretch="Fill" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
        <Image.RenderTransform>
            <CompositeTransform/>
        </Image.RenderTransform>
    </Image>

</Grid>
```

And from the code behind, I have added the following code in the MainPage Constructor:

```
    BackStoryBoard.Begin();
```

As we can see, this Storyboard enables the background image of the app to move from right to left and left to right after each 30 seconds of time interval.

Now, I have some pages and I want to use the same Storyboard effect in all of my pages. I can copy paste the same code in all of the pages but it is not a good practice. So, I have created a Resource Dictionary called Styles.xaml.

So, my Question is, how can I write the Code of the Storyboard in the Resource Dictionary and use it in my different XAML Pages? Even if I add the Storyboard, I can not call the 
**BackStoryBoard.Begin();** as it is not accessible. So, how can I resolve this problem? Any help will be highly appreciated. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try,

Merge your resource dictionary in all your needed xaml pages like,

```
<Page.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="YourDictionary.xaml"/>
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Page.Resources>
```

and from code behind,

```
var storyboard = ((this.Resources as ResourceDictionary).MergedDictionaries[0] as ResourceDictionary)["BackStoryBoard"] as Storyboard;
Storyboard.SetTarget(storyboard, image);
storyboard.Begin();
```

Hope this will solve your problem.

Comment: Cannot set a property on object 'System.Windows.Media.Animation.Storyboard' because it is in a read-only state.'